# At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs(while using JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0 and Tomcat 7.0.67)

Tags: tomcat

I am posting this after working on the example found at:
http://www.lorman.sk/pages/java/adf/ADFTomcatDemo.pdf

while using JDeveloper11.1.1.7.0,Tomcat 7.0.67

I keep getting this on tomcat 7.67
 **my catalina log**

```
 22 Jan, 2016 10:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener createMBeans
SEVERE: Exception processing Global JNDI Resources
javax.naming.NamingException: Could not load resource factory class [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory]
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:82)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:842)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:153)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:138)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:82)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:693)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:80)
    ... 23 more
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.67
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:48 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\mytomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\webapps\ADFTomcatDemo_ViewController_webapp1.war
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: 
        http://java.sun.com/jsf/html
     is already defined
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core is already defined
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:54 AM org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci onStartup
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.1) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocket JARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. 
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
22 Jan, 2016 10:43:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/ADFTomcatDemo_ViewController_webapp1] startup failed due to previous errors


**my localhost log**

22 Jan, 2016 10:55:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.bc4j.mbean.BC4JConfigLifeCycleCallBack
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1856)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1705)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5591)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1321)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:693)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:216)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2506)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
22 Jan, 2016 10:55:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE:  Configuring event listener class 'org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@40bee6b4'
22 Jan, 2016 10:55:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE:  Configuring event listener class 'org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@4ab7bdcb'
22 Jan, 2016 10:55:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
FINE:  Configuring event listener class 'org.apache.catalina.deploy.ApplicationListener@b0f7cb5f'
22 Jan, 2016 10:55:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s)
22 Jan, 2016 10:55:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStop
FINE: Stopping filters
Kindly help me out..
```